# Replace pattern with line from file using awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file first.html which contains the following code:

```
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">One</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">Two</td>
</tr>
```

Now I have another file second.txt which contains some values like:

```
Three
Four
```

I want to replace the value in each occurence of "headerValue" with the value from the second file.

Eg. after replacement first.html will become

```
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">Three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headerValue">Four</td>
</tr>
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Do you need to change the tag value for each tag having the class `headerValue` respecting the order (i.e. first tag value will have the first line of second.txt, second tag value will have the second line and so on?)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `grep` and `sed` could do the trick:

grep pattern3 from file2 ; replace pattern1 in file1 with it:

```
a="$( grep -o 'headerValue>Three' file2 )"
sed "s/headerValue>One/$a/" file1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN { i1 = 0; i2 = 0}; NR == FNR { a[i1++]=$1 }; ! /<td class="headerValue">/ && NR != FNR {print}; /<td class="headerValue">/ && NR != FNR { print gensub(/>.*</, ">"a[i2++]"<", "", $0); };' file2.txt file1.txt
```

**, where "file2.txt" contains "Three, Four, etc" and "file1.txt" contains source XML data**